# Actively used bech32(m) address with invalid checksum?

Tags: address, lightning-network, bech32-address, bip350-bech32m

The following address uses witness version 0 and its checksum is the one expected for  bech32m addresses. However, the combination of the two is not valid.

`bc1qzeya3gp8xgegkev3pgpp2r2raj65lxsansy5erdghf8mm9xze8esuwg5yh`

The address was used as part of a lightning network force-close transaction and contained funds from a timed-out HTLC. My lnd node was able to spend those funds.

Is this address valid or invalid?

https://mempool.space/address/bc1qzeya3gp8xgegkev3pgpp2r2raj65lxsansy5erdghf8mm9xze8esuwg5yh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The following address uses witness version 0

Correct.

> and its checksum is the one expected for bech32m addresses.

No, it uses the bech32 checksum. What makes you conclude that it is bech32m?

> However, the combination of the two is not valid.

Indeed. According to BIP350, witness v0 addresses must use the bech32 checksum, but witness v1 and up must use the bech32m checksum.

> Is this address valid or invalid?

Valid.

Comment: I'm sorry, I messed up. I used a shorted version of the address (bc1qzeya3gp8xgegkev3pgpp2r2raj65lxsansy5erdg) for reasons I still don't understand, and I misinterpreted an output in my debugger (in fact, the checksum is wrong both for bech32 and bech32m).